# general question about linear algebra

Tags: artificial-intelligence, linear-programming

have new discoveries been made in linear algebra since the dawn of AI or was it all "laid out" for the computer scientists by former mathematicians?

Comment: There are mathematical journals on linear algebra, which show new results in the field. Unless you are looking for some specific type of result, this question is too broad to be answered properly. Also, it seems that this question is mostly about mathematics, rather than computer science. If not, please clarify why this question is in particular about computer science.

Comment: New discoveries have been made in almost every field in general unless it has been declared dead. Or unless you consider any further or deep or different result is not linear algebra proper. Note that there have been constant discoveries in number theory. There are numbers in linear algebra.

Comment: @Apass.Jack There are numbers in my grocery bill, too. That doesn't mean that advances in number theory lead to advances in grocery shopping...

Comment: @DavidRicherby Totally agreed. Let me emphasize that there is no strict cause and effect between "Note that there have been constant discoveries in number theory. There are numbers in linear algebra." and "there are advances in linear algebra". What I meant is not a logic deduction, It is how we can understand what is happening since there are strong correlations. I did not bother to explain more since, among other reasons, this question might be closed. Please note that, as you must have been aware clearly, understanding is much more important than syllogisms sometimes.

Comment: @DavidRicherby It is your prerogative to be critical. My statement was indeed not fully self-contained. However, I would like to ask you to be somewhat cooperative instead of trivializing. You could have said, "Apass.Jack meant probably that discoveries in number theory might lead to new results in linear algebra. Discoveries in other fields might lead to new results in linear algebra as well". (There are other interpretations. For example, some advances in number theory can be regarded as advances in linear algebra.) On the other hand, I will try to be more clear and more complete.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Once again, thanks for paying attention to my comment!